# Multiple instances of "Cannot resolve method" using ActionBarSherlock with SherlockFragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having trouble regarding the ActionBarSherlock SherlockFragmentActivity. I attempted to follow [this guide](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-actionbarsherlock-side-menu-navigation-drawer-in-android/) in order to create a Navigation Drawer for the purposes I am using and I haven't been able to find another applicable guide to follow (have done multiple Google searches, scoured SO and other forums, etc.) so I come here pleading for any assistance since this is a very important project that I have been tasked with. Any assistance would be **GREATLY** appreciated since I am still in the learning stages of Android programming and cannot find another solution currently. Please help!! Thank you!

The problems that I am running into are:

1.) In MainLoader.java I keep encountering 'Cannot resolve symbol' on the following in MainLoader.java:

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

### and

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_loader, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

### also

```
// The click listener for ListView in the navigation drawer
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
        ListView.onItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
             long id) {
        selectedItem(position);
    }
}
```

### lastly

```
private void selectItem(int position) {

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        // Locate Position
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            ft.replace(R.id.main, fragment1);
            break;
        case 1:
            ft.replace(R.id.main, fragment2);
            break;
        case 2:
            ft.replace(R.id.main, fragment3);
            break;
        }
        ft.commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        // Close drawer
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
```

2.) I also receive the 'Cannot resolve symbol' on the following in MenuListAdapter.java:

### mTitle and mSubTitle

```
// Declare Variables
    Context context;
    String{} mTitle;
    String{} mSubTitle;
    int[] mIcon;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
```

mTitle and mSubtitle again (and every other instance of the two following this)

```
public MenuListAdapter(MainLoader context, String[] title, String[] subtitle,
             int[] icon) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mTitle = title;
        this.mSubTitle = subtitle;
        this.mIcon = icon;
    }
```

Here is my MainLoader.java

```
package com.marywood;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.actionbarsherlock.*;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;

import static com.marywood.R.drawable;


public class MainLoader extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    // Declare Variable
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    ListView mDrawerList;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    MenuListAdapter mMenuAdapter;
    String[] title;
    String[] subtitle;
    int[] icon;
    Fragment fragment1 = new Fragment1(); // Define Fragment 1
    Fragment fragment2 = new Fragment2(); // Define Fragment 2
    Fragment fragment3 = new Fragment3(); // Define Fragment 3

    // Action Bar error fix
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_loader);

        // Generate title
        title = new String[] { "Home", "News & Events", "Admissions"};

        // Generate subtitle
        subtitle = new String[] {};

        // Generate icon
        icon = new int[] { drawable.ic_magnifying_glass, drawable.ic_refresh, drawable.ic_compose};

        // Locate DrawerLayout in main_loader.xml
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        // Locate ListView in drawer_layout.xml
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MainList);

        // Set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        // Pass results to MenuListAdapter Class
        mMenuAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(this, title, subtitle, icon);

        // Set the MenuListAdapter to the ListView
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);

        // Capture button clicks on side menu
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        //Enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_loader, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // The click listener for ListView in the navigation drawer
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.onItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                 long id) {
            selectedItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        // Locate Position
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            ft.replace(R.id.main, fragment1);
            break;
        case 1:
            ft.replace(R.id.main, fragment2);
            break;
        case 2:
            ft.replace(R.id.main, fragment3);
            break;
        }
        ft.commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        // Close drawer
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

Here is my main_loader.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="600dp" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#015A20"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/MainList"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#850736"
        android:textColor="#FBA81A"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

drawer_list_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                style="?attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            style="?attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtitle"
            style="?attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MenuListAdapter.java

```
package com.marywood;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MenuListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    String{} mTitle;
    String{} mSubTitle;
    int[] mIcon;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MenuListAdapter(Context context, String[] title, String[] subtitle,
             int[] icon) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mTitle = title;
        this.mSubTitle = subtitle;
        this.mIcon = icon;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTitle.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mTitle[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare variables
        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtSubTitle;
        ImageView imgIcon;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, parent, false);

        // Locate the TextViews in drawer_list_item.xml
        txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        txtSubTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);

        // Locate the ImageView in drawer_list_item.xml
        imgIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        // Set the results into TextViews
        txtTitle.setText(mTitle[position]);
        txtSubTitle.setText(mSubTitle[position]);

        return itemView;

    }
}
```

To save space, I have 3 fragment java files: Fragment1.java, Fragment2.java, and Fragment3.java which all have the same code except for the inflater.inflate which reflects the proper fragment (R.layout.fragment1, container, false) etc. so I'm only putting the Fragment1.java code:

```
package com.marywood;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Fragment2 extends SherlockFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

The same case follows for the fragment XML files all having the same layout but to save space I'll display the fragment1.xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/Fragment1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And lastly the strings.xml resource file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Marywood Mobile</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
    <string name="drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>
    <string name="Fragment1">This is Fragment 1</string>
    <string name="Fragment2">This is Fragment 2</string>
    <string name="Fragment3">This is Fragment 3</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Are you referencing a jar and a library project both, of the same library? The error might happen if it is having two definitions of the same thing and so is getting confused and showing multiple instances .. error.

Comment: *NOTE* I forgot to mention that I am using Android Studio for this project (not sure if that makes a big difference or not). As far as having two definitions, is there a way to check? If the multiple definitions is the case, is there a way I can point it to a fully qualified name without it throwing the error? Thanks for the fast response!

Comment: Are you referencing any library? Right click on project and go to properties. There you can see See in `Android` if you are referencing any library and in `Java Build Path -> Libraries` if you are referencing jar of the same.

Comment: Thank you for your input, but as it turns out, ActionBarSherlock isn't really what I'm in need of.

Comment: okay. Great. So, I was right in saying that `The error might happen if it is having two definitions of the same thing and so is getting confused and showing multiple instances`. Glad finally you figured it out :). All the best

Comment: Yes! Thank you for all of your help! I would appreciate it if you could perhaps help on another question that I'll be posting shortly involving navigation drawers. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I was, in fact, accidentally importing two of the same classes (i.e. the standard app class and also the support.v4 class at the same time. Reverting these changes solved the errors.